# Maxwell Equations and Flux Continuity Law

Tags: electromagnetism

> Use Maxwell’s second equation (Faraday’s law) to prove the flux continuity law: ${\rm div} (B) = 0$, where $B$ is time-varying.

My approach would be to prove the flux continuity law using Gauss' Law for magnetic fields, but I'm unsure on how to prove it using Faraday's Law. Any hints?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\uvect}{\hat{\bf e}}$

Frist note that

$$
\nabla\cdot (\nabla\times{\bf E}) = 0 \tag{1}
$$

You can show this is true by expanding each term (abusing a bit Einstein's notation):

$$
(\uvect_i\partial_i)\cdot(\uvect_k \epsilon_{klm}\partial_l E_m) = \delta_{ik}\epsilon_{klm}\partial_i\partial_l E_m = \epsilon_{klm}\partial_i\partial_l E_m = 0 
$$

where I used the fact that $\epsilon_{klm} = -\epsilon_{lkm}$ whereas $\partial_k\partial_l E_m = \partial_l\partial_k E_m$. With this in mind note that

\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla\times{\bf E} &=& \frac{\partial{\bf B}}{\partial t} \\
\nabla\cdot(\nabla\times{\bf E}) &=& \nabla\cdot\left(\frac{\partial{\bf B}}{\partial t}\right) \\
0 &=& \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\nabla \cdot {\bf B}) \tag{2}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Very clear! Thank you very much.